# What does the fame stat do?

Tags: torchlight-2

I have a stat in my character panel called "fame".  It also says I am "respected".

What does this stat affect in the game?

Comment: In Torchlight 1, it was merely a "ranking" of sorts. Additionally, each time you increased it, you got another skill point. I'd think it'd be something similar in TL2.

Comment: It's just another progress bar to enjoy filling up.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fame is, like your experience, a statistic you acquire as you play. While you only get experience from killing regular enemies, killing champions (purple health bars) bosses (orange health bars) and completing quests will also grant you some fame.

When you get enough fame to level it up, you gain 1 additional skill point. There are 32 fame levels.

Comment: Completing quests also gives you fame

Answer (score 4):

You get 1 skill point everytime you increase your fame level.

Other then that i really haven't noticed the fame being useful for anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Actually there are 34 levels of fame (not 32)

I thought I was close to the top of the fame level at Local Hero, turned out it was only 12 on the list of 34.
Here they are listed below in order of starting fame level.
And yes each level up in fame you get an additional skill point.

1. Unrecognized
2. Barely Known
3. Recognized
4. Tolerated
5. Acknowledged
6. Respected
7. Well Known
8. Liked
9. Memorable
10. Honored
11. Prominent
12. Local Hero
13. Widely Known
14. Remarkable
15. Ascendant
16. Distinguished
17. Prestigious
18. Eminent
19. Folk Hero
20. Famous
21. Acclaimed
22. Local Legend
23. Illustrious
24. Renowned
25. Celebrated
26. Lionized
27. Glorious
28. Legendary
29. Exalted
30. Fabled
31. Mythic
32. Immortal
33. Demigod
34. Unattainable

I personally think they need to add a few more like:

Godlike

God

King of Gods

Lol...

Answer (score -3):

I think fame also makes vendors sell stuff cheaper.

I could be wrong.

Comment: This would be better as a comment, especially if you are not even sure if it is true. Or you could improve it as an answer by doing some research in to your claim.